# shmget() and shmat()

Tags: linux, c, shared-memory

Using `shmget()`, we can allocate a shared memory block of certain size in bytes and using `shmat()`, we attach this shared memory block to the address space of the calling process.

I need to check my understanding:
We have one process creating and attaching a shared memory using `shmget()` and `shmat()`, and another process that is attaching this shared memory to its address space using `shmat()`.

Now the return address of this shared memory (using the `shmat()`) is different in the two processes because this is an virtual address.

However, the shared memory block itself has a single base physical address that is mapped to different virtual addresses of the processes sharing this memory. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. It's the idea of *shared memory* that different processes can map the same actual memory; and because of virtual addressing, these addresses don't have to be the same.

You can even map the same shared memory pages into the same process twice at different addresses – that's, for example, how GNU Radio (classically) [double-maps a buffer to emulate a ring buffer, where writing at the end means writing at the beginning](https://www.gnuradio.org/blog/2017-01-05-buffers/).